# How to achieve text-decoration: 'dotted' with MaterialUI <Link>

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm struggling to effect an on-hover dotted underline on a Material-UI `<Link>` component. The following code doesn't seem to have any effect:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  link: {
    '&hover': {
      textDecoration: 'dotted'
    },
  },
}));

export default function Links() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return (
    <Typography>
      <Link
       underline={'hover'}
        href="/"
        className={classes.link}
      >
        Some anchor text
      </Link>
    </Typography>
  );
}
```

Any alternative?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me..

There were two things I had to change:

- You have to change `&hover` to `&:hover`
- You have to use `textDecorationStyle: 'dotted'`, instead of `textDecoration: 'dotted'`

[**Live Demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-dcdgfq?embed=1&file=AppLink.js)

```
import React from 'react';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import { Typography, Link } from '@material-ui/core';


const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  link: {
    '&:hover': {
      textDecorationStyle: 'dotted'
    }
  },
}));

export default function Links() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return (
    <Typography>
      <Link
        underline="hover"
        href="/"
        className={classes.link}
      >
        Some anchor text
      </Link>
    </Typography>
  );
}
```